# Randomised JMeter Test plan

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do a randomised interleaved. A cut down version is as follows.

If I have:-

```
Thread Group
   HTTP - A
   HTTP - B
      Random Controller
         HTTP - 1
         HTTP - 2
         HTTP - 3
         HTTP - 4
         HTTP - 5
         HTTP - 6
         HTTP - 7
         HTTP - B
```

I get mostly what I'm after i.e.
A,B,[Random from 1-8],A,B,[Random from 1-8] etc..

The problem is that if I set to 8 runs I don't always get each of 1-8 being run.

What I'm after is a blend with what Random Order Controller does (run each child once) but only one.

The problem with

```
Thread Group
   HTTP - A
   HTTP - B
      Random Order Controller
         HTTP - 1
         HTTP - 2
         HTTP - 3
         HTTP - 4
         HTTP - 5
         HTTP - 6
         HTTP - 7
         HTTP - B
```

Is that it does
A,B,[Randomly run each of 1-8 once] then ends.
e.g.
A,B,7,1,6,3,8,5,4,2 then ends.

What I need is the numeric requests are randomly selected but only run once each with A & B always run as interleaved requests.
e.g.
A,B,7,A,B,1,A,B,6,A,B,3,A,B,8,A,B,5,A,B,4,A,B,2

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Put everything under [Interleave Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller) and tick `ignore sub-controller blocks` box:

[image]

If you want to run the whole `A->B->X` sequence 8 times you will need to set the number of loops to `24` under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)

In general using random execution order is not the best idea as tests should (or even must) be [repeatable](https://www.ontestautomation.com/best-practice-focus-on-repeatability-of-your-automated-tests/) so maybe it worth considering using [Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability/) instead?